# Safari does not click the input[type=file] on a form I cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, frontend

I have a table that is wrapped inside a form because it is there for a batch action with all the rows.

Every row, if there's no file attached to it, should have an upload button. I could render a form for every row, hidden, inside the table, but I cannot because of the wrapping form.

So I created a dummy template form outside this table. Once the user clicks a fake upload button on the row, it clones the dummy form, sets its info with the row's info, inserts the cloned form on the DOM then it clicks the input[type=file] inside the cloned form that is now inserted on the DOM.

Works like a charm on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE but not on Safari.

On this JSFiddle URL, you will find a reproduction of what I'm trying to do. Notice that once you click the Div, it will clone the form and will trigger the click on the input if you're not in Safari. If you are, it will clone the form, but will not perform the click on that cloned form input. Once the form is already cloned, if you click the Div again, it will trigger the click.

http://jsfiddle.net/WWqK8/5/

Let me know if I didn't explain myself clearly.